# Flutter: How to erase a part of a widget with another

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, how can I add a slightly bigger circle or border at the same position as the green dot, between the grey container and the green dot, and remove the grey container behind it so that the dark blue background is visible?

The goal is to make the green dot or a counter more visible when it overlays the child (grey container).

The grey container can be any widget, that can have a badge. For a container I will just paint with path but here it is really to remove some how a part of the widget (here the grey container, but can be a image or a button ...).

[image]

Here is the desired UI:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
Stack(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 70,
      width: 250,
      color: Colors.grey,
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: -8,
      right: -8,
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Container(
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: I didn't get you , You have many questions and statement, which seems confusing , Can you please specify what you want , and what you have built so far, and what are your expectations, if you have post, tag it saying this is the desired output I am looking for, So that we get good understanding

Comment: can you break down your question or just attach a Required UI pic?

Comment: Can you share the code snippet?

Comment: Thank you for you replies @PiyushKumar and Krishna Acharya. I added the desired UI, this will help to understand what I want.

Comment: Sure I did it a few second earlier @MilanSurelia

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

Wrap your green container with another container & set outer container color same as the color of your background widget.

P.S. I have used blueGrey Color in my Background Widget & also in outer Container

```
      Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 70,
            width: 250,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: -8,
            right: -8,
            child: ClipOval(
              child: Container(
                  width: 28,
                  height: 28,
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  child: Center(
                      child: ClipOval(
                          child: Container(
                    height: 18,
                    width: 18,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  )))),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: Yes this is how I did for the example. But in the title I ask how to erase this part from the gray container. Because I'm not controlling the background and want a more versatile widget if it make sense for you.

Comment: Ok. Understood & found this interesting, will surely look into this soon.

Comment: Yes this is challenging, I'm still trying on my side with painting or other widget but for now I don't have the result. I will update if I found something.